# How do i properly replace a placeholder text in PHP/Laravel and fallback to empty string if no data to be replace

Tags: php, regex, laravel

This is the text

> Hello {first_name}, from {company}. This is your email address: {email}. Your application for {team} has been approved.

And i have these data for the placeholders. Notice that its missing `first_name` & `team`.

- company : contoso inc
- name : john doe
- email: me@contoso.com

Expected result:

> Hello, from contoso inc. This is your email address: me@contoso.com. Your application for has been approved.

Here's what i did so far.

```php
Str::of($content)->replaceMatches('/\{([^}]*)\}/', function ($match) use ($placeholders) {
            return data_get($placeholders, $match[1]);
    });
```

Which produced

`Hello , from contoso inc. This is your email address: me@contoso.com. Your application for  has been approved.`

Notice that there's space after `hello` and double space after `for`

Comment: What is your `data_get` look like? Check [this PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/Vcdo0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided is OK. But the format is not what you expect.

`data_get` will return a `null` value when data cannot be processed :

###### Format

```
Hello {first_name}, from {company}.
This is your email address: {email}.
Your application for {team} has been approved.
```

###### Result

```
Hello , from contoso inc.
This is your email address: me@contoso.com.
Your application for  has been approved.
```

`NULL` won't change anything as you expect, because **the spaces are in your format**.

You can simply add `squish` to remove all extraneous white space, and use `replace` to correct the formatting of `[SPACE],`  :

```
$text = Str::of($content)
    ->replaceMatches('/\{([^}]*)\}/', function ($match) use ($placeholders) {
        return data_get($placeholders, $match[1]);
    })
    ->replace(' ,', ',')
    ->squish();
```

```
Hello, from contoso inc.
This is your email address: me@contoso.com.
Your application for has been approved.
```

Comment: So basically we've covered these punctuation comes after the placeholder --> comma & space.